# Из исходного кода страницы получить первую ссылку на картинку

Tags: регулярные-выражения, java

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как из исходного кода страницы получить первую ссылку на картинку `.jpg, .gif` или `.png`?

Comment: Нужно выбрать первую ссылку на картинку. 
Например, `http://www.example.com/images/img.jpg`

Comment: Я же указал в теме сделать это нужно с помощью регулярных выражений.

Comment: Эта задача **не решается** с помощью регулярных выражений. Точнее, решается, но либо очень сложно, либо неправильно.

Если вы всё ещё хотите решать её с помощью регулярных выражений, воля ваша, решайте.

Comment: Первую ссылку на картинку или первую картинку?

Comment: Первая ссылка которая указывает на картинку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь честным парсером HTML. Их много, попробуйте, например, [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/).

Пример из документации, который получает ссылки на все `.png`:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect(<ваш сайт>).get();
Elements pngs = doc.select("img[src$=.png]");
```

Не пытайтесь применить регулярные выражения, если вы не [@ReinRaus](/users/481/reinraus). :-P